# android - Bottom sheet like uber app

Tags: android, material-design, bottom-sheet

I was studying the Bottom Sheet, and I built something like this from the tutorial of this [link](https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031).

I was wondering how I could put together something similar to what the Uber app does. It's a bottom sheet, which when expanded seems to be a new activity.

Does anyone know how to create something similar or have an example made?

I will leave the [link of the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1DdoN6NLDg#t=00m26s) where it shows the exact moment of the component I am looking for.

[image]
[image]

Comment: [CustomBottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) is not exactly what you want, but at least it gives you an idea.

Comment: @BurakCakir its a BottomSheet or another component to make this one? I didnt find anything about

Comment: https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet this might help u.

Comment: @RahulAbrol the examples with code are so simple. I liked this one https://camo.githubusercontent.com/d81602913dd3f1e40268cbe4dfffa9d9697f58a3/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f3265335a686f552e676966 but there`s no code example of it.

Answer (score 0):

Having searched for a similar issue. I have noticed that nobody provided a sound answer. I hope it helps someone in the future:

You have to use this library: https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel, but just as a start. You will have to make several adjustments to make it look like the Uber component. I cannot paste my code due NDA but I can say I used the demo that came within the library and added all my tweaks within the function "onPanelSlide".

Comment: Hey mate, thanks! Actually, there's a `repository` with some `Uber UX` and I used it, with some adjustments. https://github.com/mohak1712/UberUX

Comment: I liked the project. Thank you for sharing.
The Uber bottom sheet was made using the same library I used though. You can notice by the paralax of the UI elements beneath the Overlay.